# TensorFlow cannot copy Tensor with type string to device

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I cannot figure out what problem is happening here. After installing TensorFlow-GPU 2.0 and have an issue with the following minimal example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
if tf.test.is_gpu_available():
    with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
        tf_string_array = tf.constant(["TensorFlow", "Deep Learning", "AI"])
    tf_string_array.device
```

After executing my code. I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: Can't copy Tensor with type string to device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0.
```

[image]

And I was installing tensorflow to follow this blog:
[installing-tensorflow-with-cuda-cudnn-and-gpu-support-on-windows-10](https://towardsdatascience.com/installing-tensorflow-with-cuda-cudnn-and-gpu-support-on-windows-10-60693e46e781)

Answer (score -1):

Verify proper installation of tensorflow-GPU by using following steps,

- Can you check if tensorflow is using GPU,

  `import tensorflow as tf
  print(tf.test.is_gpu_available())`
- To find out which device is used, you can enable log device placement
  like this:

  `sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))`
- you can try to assign a computation to the gpu and see whether you have an error

  `import tensorflow as tf
  with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
      a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
      b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
      c = tf.matmul(a, b)
  with tf.Session() as sess:
      print (sess.run(c))`